# Can I have an If within a for

Tags: jquery, if-statement, for-loop, label

This my be a silly question but can I have an If within a for in Jquery?

The code is

```
if (this.className == 'label_radio r_off' || inp.checked) {
    var ls = gebtn(this.parentNode,'label');
    for (var i = 0; i < ls.length; i++) {
        var l = ls[i];
        console.log(l);
        if (l.className.indexOf('label_radio') == -1)  continue;
        l.className = 'label_radio r_off';
    };
    this.className = 'label_radio r_on';
    if (safari) inp.click();
} else {
    this.className = 'label_radio r_off';
    if (safari) inp.click();
};
```

Im trying to add a if within the first

```
for (var i = 0; i < ls.length; i++) {
    var l = ls[i];
    console.log(l);
    if (l.className.indexOf('label_radio') == -1)  continue;
    l.className = 'label_radio r_off';
};
```

I dont want to run this if the label has a class of "disabled "
I was think something like this but cant get it working

```
for (var i = 0; i < ls.length; i++) {
    var l = ls[i];
    console.log(l);
    if (l.className == 'disabled') {
        alert('hello');
    } else {
        if (l.className.indexOf('label_radio') == -1)  continue;
        l.className = 'label_radio r_off';
    }; 
};
```

Comment: The simple answer would be, **yes**

Comment: "This my be a silly question" --- it indeed is

Comment: Rephrase the question, writing down what exactly "doesn't work" instead of asking very generic - and extremely silly, right ) - question.

Comment: Feel free to use any JavaScript language feature with or without jQuery (or other library), they don't (and can't) prevent using them. :) BTW, beware this comparison: `l.className == 'disabled'` will fail if the given element has other classes on it besides `disabled`, for example `'disabled nice-red-rounded-borders'`

Comment: Did you try to debug your code in a better way? Firebug e.g. It really helps you and you can forget about the console.log/alert stuff.

Comment: Have a little more confident to code dude. You'll be ok

Comment: Thank you BIZICLOP, that is the reason why its not working.
The labels all have a class of "disabled label_radio".

Comment: @Richy: then you could use jQuery's `hasClass()` method: `if( $(l).hasClass('disabled') ) …` or the `is()` method: `if( $(l).is('.disabled') ) …` Of course they are somewhat slower than pure js, but whatever :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are already using jQuery, use its functions, like hasClass

> The .hasClass() method will return true if the class is assigned to an
>   element, even if other classes also are.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/

Resulting in something like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < ls.length; i++) {
    var l = ls[i];
    console.log(l);
    if ($(l).hasClass('disabled')) {
        alert('hello');
    } else {
        if ($(l).hasClass('label_radio'))  continue;
        l.className = 'label_radio r_off';
    }; 
};
```

Comment: It might be useful to cache the jQueryfied element at the beginning of the loop body like `for(…){ var l=…, $l=$(l); … if( $l.hasClass()) …`

Answer (score 1):

Thank for all the help.... and comments

should have been

```
if (l.className == 'disabled label_radio') {

     } else {
           if (l.className.indexOf('label_radio') == -1)  continue;
            l.className = 'label_radio r_off';
     };
```

Comment: The order and the (amount and type of) separators between class names might be different, especially if you manipulate them from scripts. Think about classNames like `' label_radio\t\ndisabled-person'` :)